# Is it possible to find such a $l$,which that the known counter-example is only $l$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, examples-counterexamples, collatz-conjecture

Is it possible to find such a $l$,which that ***the known counter-example*** is only $l$, for any $k$, $f^k(n)≠1$? [Is there a modified Collatz rule 3n+$l$ where there is only one loop or "counter-example" and is not 3n+1?] 
$$f(n) = \begin{cases} n/2 &\text{if } n \equiv 0 \pmod{2}\\ 3n+l & \text{if } n\equiv 1 \pmod{2} .\end{cases}$$

Here, $l$  is odd number and $l
≠1$

Because, for $n=l$ , $l$ is counterexample.

For example: $l=7$

The known counterexample are $(5,1),(7,7).$ [[According to P..]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211187/what-is-known-about-collatz-like-3n-k)
[In other words, 3n+7 has two loops or two "counter-examples": 5-22-11-40-20-10-5... and 7-28-17-7...]

But, I'm looking for the *known counterexample* for function $f(n)$ is only $l$.
 I have tried many. But I did not succeed. Is there such a $l$ ?

*If the question is unclear, please edit... I did everything I could.*

Comment: What is it a counter-example to? This question is missing some context? Can you supply a more clear statement of what you are looking for? This looks like it is related to the Collatz conjecture, but it is unclear.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I'm trying to edit....

Comment: Are you trying to find loops aside from the 4-2-1 loop for 3n+1 in different rules such as 3n+5? If so, I may be able to answer your question.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews  I did everything I could...

Comment: OP, if you speak English as a second language, maybe you could ask someone to interpret your question. As it stands, it's really not clear what you're asking :)

Comment: @Griffon Theorust697 I'm looking for counterexample is only $l$.

Comment: @Jam yes, I use google translate.

Comment: Hmmm... for 3n+5, n=5, 3(5)+5 = 20, 20/2 = 10, 10/2 = 5... The loop is 20-10-5 and 5=n. Is 20-10-5 a counterexample?

Comment: I sorry, but what does "looking for counterexample is only $l$" mean?
 Counterexample to what?

Comment: We can't edit your question because we'd need to know what your question means to make it more clear.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't think "Counterexample" here means a literal counterexample to the Collatz Conjecture. I think it means he is trying to find a number that doesn't work with his equation, which is a little tricky because I believe he is working with modified Collatz rules such as 3x+5 and 3x+7. I know in 3x+7 there is a 5-22-11-40-20-10-5-... loop.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Counterexample must be only $l$.

Comment: Sigh, I know it must be only $l$. What statement is $l$ supposed to be a counter-example to?

Comment: İt must be a "Counterexample" for $f(n)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two rules I am aware of that provide 1 "counterexample" for $l$:

$3n+3$ and $3n+9$

It is unproven if these are the only "counterexamples" for all numbers because we do not know if the Collatz Conjecture is true. However,

[I checked both $3n+3$ and $3n+9$ for 1,000,000 starting numbers.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzfYa_--3heeVkNHYU5BR3BxRnM?usp=sharing)

There was only 1 "counterexample" or loop for each:

$3n+3$: 12-6-3

$3n+9$: 36-18-9

*Note: The files I uploaded are huge. You may need to download them.*

*I used some code I already wrote in Java that keeps track of the number of cycles and then dump the results into a .csv file. Since Excel can only hold so may numbers, I restricted my sample size to 1,000,000.*

Gottfried Helms also worked on this problem and goes into greater detail [here](http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz_3x_r.pdf).

Comment: Ohh..you understand my question is wrong..

Comment: Sorry for absence. I had class. Do you want list of loops? Example: 3n+5, 8-4-2-1, 20-10-5, 19-62-31-98-49-152-76-38-19...

Comment: Noo...I think my problem is english language.

Comment: I understand that Google Translate is not good for translation and I am sorry some people were mean.  I want to help you, I do not know if I answered your question correctly. If I am wrong, I will change my answer.

Comment: Do you know English well?

Comment: English is my first language. Sadly, I am not Bilingual. What is your first language?

Comment: Look at this link ✓ answer 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211187/what-is-known-about-collatz-like-3n-k

Comment: I'm looking for counterexample , which that is only $l$.

Comment: Try 3n+3? 3n+9?

Comment: I tried only bruteforce with hand..Because I dont know phyton and other languages. Is the question clear now?

Comment: I changed my answer. Please let me know if it is helpful. If this was helpful, I can edit your question.

Comment: Finally, you understand me correctly...thank you so much!!