# Proof verification: $3n+3^k$ problem equivalent to the Collatz problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, solution-verification, collatz-conjecture

The Collatz conjecture asserts that a sequence defined by repeatedly applying the function
\begin{align}
 T_0(n) &= \begin{cases}
   (3n + 1) / 2, & \text{for odd $n$,}\\
   n / 2,        & \text{for even $n$,}\\
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
always converges to the cycle passing through the number 1 for arbitrary positive integer $n$.

**Theorem.**
As long as the $T_0$ iterates converge to 1,
a sequence defined by repeatedly applying the function
\begin{align}
 T_k(n) &= \begin{cases}
   (3n + 3^k) / 2, & \text{for odd $n$,}\\
   n / 2,          & \text{for even $n$,}\\
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
converges to the cycle passing through the number $3^k$ for arbitrary positive integers $n$ and $k$.

*Proof.*
The function $T_{k}(n)$ can be adjusted for multiples of three using
\begin{align} \label{eqn:3T0n}
 3 \cdot T_{k}(n) = \begin{cases}
   (3 \cdot 3n + 3^k \cdot 3) / 2, & \text{for odd $n$,}\\
   3n/2,                           & \text{for even $n$.}\\
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
Now substitute $3n$ for $m$ ($m$ is a multiple of 3), thus $3 \cdot T_{k}(n) = T_{k+1}(3n)$, and therefore
\begin{align} \label{eqn:T1m}
 T_{k+1}(m) = \begin{cases}
   (3m + 3^{k+1}) / 2, & \text{for odd $m$,}\\
   m/2,                & \text{for even $m$.}\\
  \end{cases}
\end{align}
Note that $3n$ is odd when $n$ is odd and $3n$ is even when $n$ is even.
It means that the sequence of $T_{k+1}$ iterates for $m=3n$ is exactly the sequence of $T_{k}$ iterates for $n$ multiplied by 3.

Now we know what happens to the trajectory of $T_{k+1}$ if $m$ is a multiple of 3.
It remains to show what happens to this trajectory if $m$ is not a multiple of 3.
If such a number is even, then we can repeatedly pull out all the factors of 2 (the even branch of $T_{k+1}$), and finally get an odd number.
Thus we focus on odd $m$.
A single iterate of the $T_{k+1}$ function give us $(3m + 3) / 2$ (the odd branch of $T_{k+1}$), where $(3m + 3) / 2$ is a multiple of 3 ($3m+3$ is obviously multiple of 3, the division by $2$ has no effect on divisibility by 3).
Note that the iterates of $T_{k+1}$ converges to the cycle passing through the number $3^{k+1}$, which corresponds to $T_0(n) = 1$.
$\Box$

There are a few doubts that I have concerning this proof:

- Do the functions $T_k$ and $T_{k+1}$ in the first paragraph make sense? I rewrote them several times.
- Is there any clue missing from the proof? It seems to me that not all the sentences connect to each other.
- Is there any information missing in the proof? For example, I didn't mention what cycles are made of.
- Is there something clearly wrong here?

I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Are you working on collatz conjecture? Your previous questions tell so.

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsVeryBad Yes. I mainly deal with computer verification.

Comment: I don't understand why you seem to have an argument for you formula for $T_{k+1}(m)$ .  That formula just repeats the definition of the function.

Comment: And, later, when arguing about the "odd branch" of iterates of $T_{k+1}$ you appear to lose the dependence on $k$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @DaBler I didn't downvote, so I obviously can't state why those members did that. Nonetheless, even though this is from over a year ago, the meta post [Is there an appropriate stackexchange site related to speculative mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34538), and in particular my answer there, provides some potential reasons.

Comment: Don't know whether you know my discussion of the "3x+r" - generalization; if not perhaps it gives a/the clue... https://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz_3x_r.pdf

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Very interesting... in your Table 1, you can see 3x+1, 3x+3, 3x+9, 3x+27 which have no apparent cycle other than a trivial one. Also in the Appendix, you can see that these cases (r=1, r=3, r=9, r=27) lead to the trivial cycle passing through the number a_min = 1, 3, 9, 27. If you were to examine 81 further, you would see the same pattern.

Comment: Yes - this follows for all $r=3^k$ . And my hypothese is: no new "extra" cycles besides the "generalized trivial one" occurs for powers of 3 in $r$. (This would follow since the denominator $2^S-3^N$ and from this $q$ cannot have a factor which is an integer power of $3$ except for $S=2$ and $S=1$ and $N=1$)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Your hypothesis is essentially equivalent to my theorem. If you try to go through my proof, everything should become clearer to you.

Comment: (at) DaBler - yes; I didn't see anything incorrect in your thoughts (only skimming through). But you had questions, so I thought my essay might contain some more obvious derivation (besides that remaining/persistent "hypothesis" of mine)

Comment: To provide a summary of my proof: The first part of the proof shows that the sequence of $T_{k+1}(3n)$ iterates is exactly the sequence of $T_k(n)$ iterates multiplied by 3. The second part of the proof discloses what happens to $T_{k+1}(m)$ if $m$ is not a multiple of 3.

Comment: Yes you can delete the factors of 2. They only cause more confusion when studying the dynamical system in base 2. The factors of two is just empty space. Look at it like the trailing zeroes of a bit string number, but where the bits only represent an odd number during the entire dynamical process.

Answer (score 1):

*(this late answer was originally meant for MSE-question [About Collatz 3n+3?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211061/about-collatz-3n3?noredirect=1&lq=1) but possibly fits better here)*

Looking at the more general question for $3x+r$ might simplify the understanding as well for the the special case where $r=3$ or even $r=3^k$.

**Preliminaries**
The Syracuse-notation for the Collatz-transformation might be written in this form for odd positive elements $a_k$ and positive integer parameters $A_k$ in the exponents:
$$ T_{3,1}:= \qquad  a_{k+1} = {3a_k+ 1\over 2^{A_k}}  \tag {1.1} $$
Iterating this to $N$ steps can be written as
$$ a_{k+N} = { 3^N  \over 2^S } a_k + { 3^{N-1} + 3^{N-2} 2^{A_1} + 3^{N-3} 2^{A_1+A_2} + \cdots 2^{A_1 + ...+ A_{N-1} }   \over 2^S} \tag {1.2}
$$
where here (and always in the following) I denote $S = \sum_{k=1}^N A_k$.

I find it useful to introduce a notation for the long numerator in eq 1.2 :
$$ \text{using } \qquad E_{N,S} = [A_1,A_2,...,A_k,...,A_N] \qquad \text{ then } \\
Q(E_{N,S}) =  3^{N-1} + 3^{N-2} 2^{A_1} + 3^{N-3} 2^{A_1+A_2} + \cdots 2^{A_1 + ... +A_{N-1} } \tag {1.3}
$$
We have then the expression for an $N$-step iteration from some $a_1$ to $a_{N+1}$ in a much shorter form as
$$ T_{3,1}^{\circ N}:= \qquad a_{1+N} = { 3^N  \over 2^S } a_1 + { Q(E_{N,S}) \over 2^S} \tag {1.4}
$$
and the expression for the first element $a_1$ in a cycle *(when $a_1 = a_{N+1}$)* of $N$ (odd) steps and $S$ divisions by $2$,  with some exponent vector of $A_k$'s (use the symbol $E_{N,S}$ for its representation) by
$$   a_1 = {Q(E_{N,S}) \over 2^S - 3^N } \tag {1.5}
$$

---

**Derivations** Now for the generalization $r$ of the summand in eq 1.1
$$ T_{3,r}:= \qquad a_{k+1} = {3a_k+ r\over 2^{A_k}}  \tag {2.1} $$
it comes out that the function $Q()$ is not affected by this generalization and only eq 1.4 changes minimally:
$$ a_{1+N} = { 3^N  \over 2^S } a_1 + {r \cdot Q(E_{N,S}) \over 2^S} \tag {2.4}
$$
and as well for the cycle-formula:
$$   a_1 = { r \cdot Q(E_{N,S}) \over 2^S - 3^N } \tag {2.5}
$$

---

From eq 2.4 we see the equivalence of the $T_{3,r}()$-transformation with the original Syracuse if we replace the $a_k$ by $r \cdot b_k$. We get then
$$ r \cdot b_{1+N} = { 3^N  \over 2^S } r \cdot b_1 + {r \cdot Q(E_{N,S}) \over 2^S} \tag {3.1a}
$$
and cancelling the factor $r$ we get
$$  b_{1+N} = { 3^N  \over 2^S }  b_1 + { Q(E_{N,S}) \over 2^S} \tag {3.1b}
$$
which is simply the Syracuse-formulation on the variables $b_k$.
For instance for $a_1=15 = 3 \cdot 5$ we have with $r=3$ the obvious equivalence
$$   T_{3,3}:  3\cdot 1 = {(3 \cdot 5) \cdot 3+3 \over 2^4 } \\
 \sim T_{3,1}: 1 \cdot 1 = {(1 \cdot 5) \cdot 3+1 \over 2^4 }  \tag {3.2a}
  $$
as well as after allowance of fractional values for the $T_{3,1}$-Syracuse transformation:
$$   T_{3,3}:  3 = { 7\cdot 3+3 \over 2^3 } \\
 \sim T_{3,1}: 1=(3/3) = {(7/3) \cdot 3+1 \over 2^3 }  \tag {3.2b}
  $$

---

Aside of this instructive representation of equivalency between $T_{3,r}$ and $T_{3,1}$ there occurs here first time the problem of dealing with fractional values in the Collatz-problem. It is of course not a big problem to extend the domain for the Collatz-conjecture to *fractional* values, but once we allow fractional values in the $a_k$ then we shall as well introduce the possibilities of non-integer elements on cycles.

The Collatz-problem is then, more explicitely: "there is no cycle ***in integral values*** $a_k>0$ other than $a_k=1$" - but on fractional values cycles might occur!

We start at the cycle-equation eq 2.5:
$$   a_1 = { r \cdot Q(E_{N,S}) \over 2^S - 3^N } \tag {4.1}
$$
Let us assume, there are no non-trivial cycles for the Collatz-problem, operationalized by the $T_{3,1}$-definition eq 1.1 . Once allowing fractional values we can only say: no ***integer-valued*** cycles. It implies, that, given some $N$ and from this $S$, the primefactors in the denominator cannot all be cancelled by the function $Q(E_{N,S})$ in the numerator.
Let's see one example. Assume $N=3$ and $S=5$. Then for $T_{3,1}$ we get
$$ a_1  = { 1 \cdot Q(E_{N,S}) \over 32 - 27 } = { Q([A_1,A_2,A_3]) \over 5 } \tag {4.2} $$
and no configuration $\small [A_1,A_2,A_3]$ with $\small A_1+A_2+A_3=S=5$ produces a primefactor $5$ in the numerator and so we stay with a fractional result for $a_1$.
But if we use $r=5$ and thus the transformation $T_{3,5}$ we get
$$ a_1  = { 5 \cdot Q(E_{N,S}) \over 32 - 27 } = { 5 \cdot Q([A_1,A_2,A_3]) \over 5 } = Q([A_1,A_2,A_3]) \tag {4.3} $$
and the following solutions are all integral in $a_k$:
$$ a_1=Q([1,1,3]) \qquad a_2=Q([1,3,1]) \qquad a_3=Q([3,1,1])  \\
 a_1=Q([1,2,2] \qquad a_2=Q([2,2,1]) \qquad a_3=Q([2,1,2])  \tag {4.4}
  $$
where we have two solutions for $a_1$, each with 3 needed rotations each.

Another example: for the 5-odd-step-cycle  $N=5$ from where $S=8$ we have in the denominator $2^8 - 3^5=13$ and thus $r=13$ allows one or more cycles.
By the possible combinations of the exponents $A_k$ (resp. rotations) we find a couple of cycles already mentioned elsewhere in MSE
$$\small \begin{array} {llll}
a_1=Q([1,1,1,1,4]) & a_2=Q([1,1,1,4,1]) & a_3=Q([1,1,4,1,1]) & \ldots \phantom{\vdots} \\
a_1=Q([1,1,1,2,3]) & a_2=Q([1,1,2,3,1]) & a_3=Q([1,2,3,1,1]) & \ldots \phantom{\vdots}  \\
a_1=Q([1,1,2,2,2]) & a_2=Q([1,2,2,2,1]) & a_3=Q([2,2,2,1,1]) & \ldots \phantom{\vdots}  \\
a_1 = \; \vdots       &  a_2 = \; \vdots & a_3 = \; \vdots & \ldots \\
\end{array} \tag {4.5}
$$
*(giving $7$ cycles (and their rotations) all with $(N,S)=(5,8)$ )*

---

From this we have now a simple recipe to find some $r$ which allows integer cycles for any $N$ *(and its according $S$ where $S=\small \lceil N \cdot \log_2(3) \rceil$)* : simply use some $r$ which cancels the primefactors in the denominator $\small 2^S-3^N$ by the factors of $r \cdot \small Q(E_{N,S})$.

---

This last consideration implies as well one more property: since in the denominator there will never occur a primefactor $3$ no $r=3^k$ can have any effect on the cancelling property and any $r=3^k$ shall have no more nontrivial cycles than the original Collatz-transformation $T_{3,1}$ (thus as far as we know: no nontrivial cycles at all).